# Bind data to grid after page load MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have problem here.With kendo grid i'm loading data from some action in controller.But in the last column  i have link which should fire another action in same controller.When i delete this piece of code

```
                     type: "json",
                   transport: {
                       read: {
                           url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ListFinances", "Jobs"))",
                           type: "POST",
                           dataType: "json",
                           data: additionalData
                       },

                   },
                   schema: {
                       data: "Data",
                       total: "Total",
                       errors: "Errors"
                   },
```

last column is working perfect,bit when is present this piece of code, last column is not working>please here some help, i;m new to mvc.Below is the code:

```
                    $("#jobs-grid").kendoGrid({
                            dataSource: {
                                data: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.FinishedJobs)),
                                schema: {
                                    model: {
                                        fields: {
                                            JobNumber: { type: "string" },
                                            CustomerId: { type: "number" },
                                            JobCount: { type: "number" },
                                            JobYear: { type: "number" },
                                            Status: { type: "number" },
                                            Position: { type: "number" },
                                            Finished: { type: "boolean" },
                                            HasInvoice: { type: "boolean" },
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                type: "json",
                   transport: {
                       read: {
                           url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ListFinances", "Jobs"))",
                           type: "POST",
                           dataType: "json",
                           data: additionalData
                       },

                   },
                   schema: {
                       data: "Data",
                       total: "Total",
                       errors: "Errors"
                   },
                                error: function(e) {
                                    display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                                    // Cancel the changes
                                    this.cancelChanges();
                                },
                                pageSize: 20,
                                serverPaging: true,
                                serverFiltering: true,
                                serverSorting: true
                            },

                            //dataBound: onDataBound,
                            columns: [
                                @*{
                                            field: "Status",
                                            title: "Status",
                                            template: '#= Status #'
                                        },*@
                                {
                                    field: "JobNumber",
                                    title: "jobNumber",
                                    template: '#= JobNumber #'
                                },
                                {
                                    field: "CustomerId",
                                    title: "Customer",
                                    template: '#= Customer.Name #'
                                },
                                {
                                    field: "Id",
                                    title: "Id"
                                },

                                @*{
                                            field: "ShortDesc",
                                            title: "ShortDesc"
                                        },*@
                                {
                                    field: "DateCompletition",
                                    title: "DateCompletition"
                                },
                                {
                                    field: "Id",
                                    title: "@T("Common.Edit")",
                                    width: 130,
                                    template: '<a href="../Finances/Edit/#=Id#">Edit</a>'
                                }
                            ],
                            pageable: {
                                refresh: true,
                                pageSizes: [5, 10, 20, 50]
                            },
                            editable: {
                                confirmation: false,
                                mode: "inline"
                            },
                            scrollable: false,
                            //  sortable: true,
                            //  navigatable: true,
                            //   filterable: true,
                            //  scrollable: true,
                            selectable: true

                        });
                    });
        </script>
```

Comment: what is @T you are using?, your code contains errors

Comment: it's translate list, dont see it, it;s not important

Comment: your javascript code for instance `title: "@T("Common.Edit")",` should be written as follows `title: '@T("Common.Edit")'` since its mixed between server code and client code

Comment: @HadiHassan i've edited, delete it @T

Comment: @HadiHassan i;ve tried, but nothing is changed, edit link not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want  to add a `command` to the grid, The  way to add a command  as described [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/custom-command) is as follows

```
   var grid = $("#jobs-grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                           pageSize: 20,
                           data: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.FinishedJobs)),
                        },
                        pageable: true,
                        height: 550,
                        columns: [
                            { field: "JobNumber", title: "JobNumber", width: "140px" },
                            { field: "CustomerId", title: "Customer", width: "140px" },
                            { field: "Id", title:"Id" },
                            { field: "DateCompletition", title:"DateCompletition" },
                            { command: { text: "Edit", 
                                         click: function(e){
                                              // here you can add your code
                                          }}, 
                              title: " ", 
                              width: "180px" }]
                    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

You might have a look on the documentation of the kendo grid [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.command)

Hope this will help you

Comment: in this function, you should write what actually you want the behavior, for example, to hide the grid and show partial view for edit or to popup a window and display the edit view inside, depends on what scenario you want and all cases, you need to use something like $.ajax call

Comment: moreover, there are built in actions for the grid like edit and destroy, you can use for example: command:'destroy'